# assembly - mov unitialized variable?

Tags: c, assembly, linker

I have a hard time understanding a piece of code.
I read the xv6 lecture [at line 1054](http://pdosnew.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2014/xv6/book-rev8.pdf)

**Here is the code** :

```
.globl entry
entry:
  # Turn on page size extension for 4Mbyte pages
  movl    %cr4, %eax
  orl     $(CR4_PSE), %eax
  movl    %eax, %cr4
  # Set page directory
  movl    $(V2P_WO(entrypgdir)), %eax
  movl    %eax, %cr3
  # Turn on paging.
  movl    %cr0, %eax
  orl     $(CR0_PG|CR0_WP), %eax
  movl    %eax, %cr0

  # Set up the stack pointer.
  movl $(stack + KSTACKSIZE), %esp

  # Jump to main(), and switch to executing at
  # high addresses. The indirect call is needed because
  # the assembler produces a PC-relative instruction
  # for a direct jump.
  mov $main, %eax
  jmp *%eax

.comm stack, KSTACKSIZE
```

**My question is**:

How is it possible that we `movl $(stack + KSTACKSIZE), %esp` when `stack` is defined nowhere in the project, but at line 1063 as a .comm symbol and in a function that is called later and redefines the stack variable as a local one

```
static void
startothers(void)
{
  char *stack; // THIS ONE IS A DIFFERENT BEAST, right ?
  ...
    // Tell entryother.S what stack to use, where to enter, and what 
    // pgdir to use. We cannot use kpgdir yet, because the AP processor
    // is running in low  memory, so we use entrypgdir for the APs too.
    stack = kalloc();
    *(void**)(code-4) = stack + KSTACKSIZE;
    *(void**)(code-8) = mpenter;
    *(int**)(code-12) = (void *) v2p(entrypgdir);
```

?

I may miss a trick, but I don't get when its address is set.

At the linking stage so that stack is actually defined ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes `.comm` defines and allocates the `stack` with the given `STACKSIZE` in the `.bss` section. Upon first exeuction, the code runs as-is, and uses that stack. Judging from the function name of `startothers` I assume this is a multiprocessor bootup. Once the initial cpu has been brought up, it allocates a new stack for each other processor, and modifies the code itself so that it uses the newly allocated one.

In my opinion it would be a lot less confusing if the `entry` used variables for these things.

Comment: Thanks Jester. I was struggling a bit but your explanation enables me to keep going with the satisfaction of being sure to understand.